# Timer to turn on/off apps

Tags: 14.04

I need an app to turn on/off apps at a specified time: turn on transmisson at 0:00 and turn it off at 6:00.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One such app is [GNOME Schedule](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-schedule/). To install, look it up in the Ubuntu Software Centre or use

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

in the terminal.

Once installed, go to System -> Preferences -> Scheduled tasks. This will open the configuration window.